# Unable to tunnel through proxy - HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: integration, apex-webservice

I have built an integration in sandbox, I have deployed the web service code to production and I obtained this error: **EXCEPTION: System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"**
This error only appears in Production, in sandbox works OK, and in postman works fine too.
The integration on sandbox is similar to the production.
What could be the problem? Could be an error from the server or SFDC?

Comment: This is just happening to me as well. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I'm not sorry. It showed up and fixed itself. It was a mystery

Comment: Thanks... I'm trying to have the partner whitelist all the Salesforce IP addresses, though they assure me there aren't any IP restrictions in place. Weird.